# Application Error: Exception EFOpenError in module some xyz.dll at 00039BB3

Tags: c++, dll, c++builder-5

I am working in an application which is written in Borland C++Builder 5. Also, I have one DLL for camera functionalities, which will be loaded statically by the main application.

I am facing the following error frequently, I don't know what it is:

> Exception EFOpenError in module .dll at 00039BB3

If this error occurs, replacing the same copy of DLL is not working. Instead, I have to rebuild the DLL and run the application again.

Please help me to understand and solve this error.

Comment: Did you try running the code in the debugger to see where `EFOpenError` is actually being thrown from, and to look at the call stack leading up to the exception? (Hint - it is thrown from the `TFileStream` constructor when the `Mode` parameter does not have the `fmCreate` flag and the `Sysutils::FileOpen()` function fails.) `TFileStream` is not used during DLL loading, so it has to be something in your own code that is attempting to open a file. The `Message` of the exception should explain why the file could not be opened (for instance, if the requested file does not exist).

Comment: Exactly.You are right @RemyLebeau. Before i open the particular file for processing, it is moved from parent folder for next process. I have corrected the code and it is working now. Thank you.